# Why runtime compilation fails for WDK?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, java-11, java-17

Changed jdk 17 folder location and intellij picked Jdk 11 and now tomcat cannot start.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnYsi.png). Getting this error on login

Tomcat should have worked fine. Can somebody help where I have to change JDK 11 to JDK 17 so that it works fine?

Comment: Images of text should be avoided, ref: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Try to configure JDK in IntelliJ from scratch as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#define-sdk